Content creator tax obligations
I create music and upload to YouTube. I bought equipment, editing software, etc for my band last year (2023) but I just started releasing the videos on Youtube this year (2024).

Can I still claim the expenses on my taxes?
Do I need to have monetized the videos to claim it?
I was going to claim myself as a sole business owner. Do I need to be under a certain banner such as LLC or something to claim deductions?


What country are you in?

What's the actual business here? You've mentioned no revenues whatsoever and it doesn't sound like you have an actual viable business.

The "business", if there turns out to be one, amounts to publishing a series of articles and hoping they bring in revenue. But it's a bleeping lot harder to produce income that way than people think it is -- the competition for attention is obscene, and even if you're much better than most it takes a lot of  time and effort to find a significant audience. And you have to publish continuously while maintaining quality if you want to maintain that income stream. I really would call it a hobby and not try to claim the expenses until/unless you can prove it's producing net income.

Makes sense, thank you!

Assuming United States (you didn't say):
The IRS understands that new businesses may take a few years to show profit. But if you don't show income pretty soon, and you aren't a clearly established business in development mode, they're likely to tell you that you should have called this a hobby and not deducted costs, and make you re-file with that correction.
So. Yes, monetizing the videos would help. But they still may tell you it should be considered hobby income until the numbers becomes significant.
Personally I wouldn't try to claim it as anything but hobby until you're getting at least a kilo buck a year in gross receipts.
